# Beginner: Justify Text

Tags: css, text, justify

I am beginner working for a class assignment and I am having some difficulty when trying to justify the text in one of my sites.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this!

HTML:

```
<div class="about__entry sm-two-thirds">
    <p>We believe in the power of authentic and genuine music, not manufactured artists. We believe in the freedom of music, expression, and creativity. We aim to give artists tools that will empower them to make the music they love and give them the ability to take their careers into their own hands.</p>
</div><!-- end .about__entry -->
```

CSS

```
.About__entry {
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
    text-align-last:center;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

CSS is case sensitive e.g. for class names.

`About__entry != about__entry`

Comment: Yes, just saw that! Thanks, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fixed example: https://jsfiddle.net/v6L94v27/

You just needed to match the case for the class name (Class name had a capital A)

```
<div class="About__entry sm-two-thirds">
         <p>We believe in the power of authentic and genuine music, not manufactured artists. We believe in the freedom of music, expression, and creativity. We aim to give artists tools that will empower them to make the music they love and give them the ability to take their careers into their own hands.</p>
    </div><!-- end .about__entry -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I really appreciate it!